# Exchange PowerShell in a Scheduled Task runs forever

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, powershell, scheduled-task

I have a couple of Exchange 2010 PowerShell scripts that I'd like to run as Scheduled Tasks.

If I launch PowerShell using "Run as different user" I can run the scripts and they execute correctly.

If I schedule a task using that same user, the task stays in the Running state forever.

How can I figure out where the task is getting stuck?

For reference, here's how I enable the Exchange stuff:

```
. 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto
```

And here is the ways I have tried to run the script from the Task Scheduler:

- powershell -command "& {. 'c:\windows\script.ps1' }"
- powershell -file 'c:\windows\script.ps1'
- powershell -file "c:\windows\script.ps1"

All with the same result. Grr...

Comment: Commenting late to the party, but I had the same behavior.  A scheduled task registered using PowerShell's `Register-ScheduledJob` never 'ended' it did end once I closed my PowerShell console and ISE.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to modify your execution policy, or specify the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` as a commandline parameter.

```
powershell -Command "<path to .ps1 script>" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Comment: I added the ExecutionPolicy option to my command line parameters. No change; task still runs forever.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is how you are doing it, but when I am running PowerShell scripts via task scheduler I use the "Start a program" action and select powershell and then add the arguments from there. That might be what you are doing here, but it's kind of unclear. 
Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Per TheCompWiz execution policy might also be an issue.

Comment: That's not even valid command line syntax for powershell.exe, but just for the heck of it I tried it. The task immediately failed.

Comment: Interesting because all of my daily powershell tasks run that way and they function just fine.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "& 'c:\windows\script.ps1' "

Comment: ah, there's the difference. your screenshot doesn't show the `-command`

Comment: Yeah, I actually personally don't use -command, but it is probably the proper use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case the solution was to specify the "start in" directory (my script would read the contents of a file which it wouldn't find because I didn't specify the full path to the file).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the comment by "user279399" to use the taskkill command was super helpful, just needed modification. Here's my solution at the end of the argument syntax

```
taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq domain\exchadmin" /im powershell.exe
```

This command kills only the powershell session that's running under that user account. It is best practice to have a separate exchange admin account for running scheduled tasks.

Answer (score -3):

Try add to the end of your script [taskkill /f /im "powershell.exe"] this will kill all "powershell.exe" processes. I don't know how to kill the current power-shell process (equivalent to [cmd.exe /c]). But it will do the trick.

Comment: And what if there were another powershell scripts running, probably doing something important? Would you just kill these processes without asking? On a production environment? As a routine? Seriously?!